# Problem with unicode String literal in unit test

Tags: java, macos, unicode, encoding

I have a JUnit test that tests adding Strings to a Dictionary custom type.  Everything works fine for everyone else on a Linux/Windows machine, however, being the first dev in my shop on a mac, this unit test fails for me.  The offending lines are where unicode string literals are used:

```
    dict.add( "Su字/会意pin", "Su字/会意pin" );
    dict.add( "字/会意", "字/会意" );
```

Is there a platform-independent way to specify the unicode string?  I've tried changing the encoding of the file in Eclipse to UTF-8 instead of the default MacRoman, but the test still fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the flags for the javac compiler, set the -encoding flag, so in your case you'd mark it as

```
javac -encoding UTF-8
```